# Can I change default connection limit self hosted web api (owin)?

Tags: rest, web-applications, owin, self-hosting

[OWIN] Can I change default connection limit self hosted web api?
And how can I do it?

Comment: Haven't any recommendation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find any recommendation!!!